# How can I get the size of every image to store it in Database in Dropzone

Tags: image, drag-and-drop, dropzone.js

I want to store the size of every uploading image in database.How can I get the size of uploading images to store it in database in dropzone? Plz tell me step by step as I am new in Programming

```
        var file_up_names = new Array;
    Dropzone.options.dropzoneJsForm = {
        parallelUploads: 10,
        maxFiles: 10,
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",

        init: function () {
            var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-all");

            var myDropzone = this; //closure

            submitButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
                myDropzone.processQueue(); //tell Dropzone to process all queued files
                if (myDropzone.files.length <= 0) {
                    window.location.href = "/product/uploadauctionimages/" + '@JTJapan.Core.Helper.AuthBase.ProductId.ToString()'
                }
            });

            // redirection On Upload Completion
            myDropzone.on("complete", function (file) {
                if (myDropzone.getUploadingFiles().length === 0 && myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length === 0) {
                    window.location.href = "/product/uploadauctionimages/" + '@JTJapan.Core.Helper.AuthBase.ProductId.ToString()'
                }
            });

            //Call the action method to load the images from the server
            var dbfileCount = 0;
            $.getJSON("/product/getattachments", function (data) { // get the json response

                $.each(data, function (key, value) { //loop through it
                    var mockFile = { id: value.AttachmentID, name: value.FileName, size: "10" }; // here we get the file name and size as response

                    myDropzone.options.addedfile.call(myDropzone, mockFile);

                    myDropzone.options.thumbnail.call(myDropzone, mockFile, value.Path);//uploadsfolder is the folder where you have all those uploaded files

                    myDropzone.options.maxFiles = myDropzone.options.maxFiles - 1;
                    file_up_names.push(value.AttachmentID);
                });

            });
```